# How to return output of module

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am creating two Azure App Services and 2 App Service Plans using `For Loop` but I need to pass the `HostingPlanID` from the AppService plan to each of the App Services, but I'm unable to access the output of the module.

I'm getting the following error
`Cannot access properties of type "module[]". An "object" type is required.`

within my App Service Plan Module, I am creating an output `output hostingPlanId string = hostingPlan.id`

But i can't reference this from my template `(main.bicep)`

`hostingPlan: AppServicePlan.hostingPlan.id`

Module:

```
param appPlanSkuCode string
param appPlanSkuTier string
param appPlanOS string
param appPlanSize string
param appPlanFamily string
param appPlanCapacity int
param hostingPlanName string



resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-10-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: appPlanOS
  sku: {
    name: appPlanSkuCode
    tier: appPlanSkuTier
    size: appPlanSize
    family: appPlanFamily
    capacity: appPlanCapacity
  }
  properties: {
    perSiteScaling: false
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: 1
    isSpot: false
    reserved: true
    isXenon: false
    hyperV: false
    targetWorkerCount: 0
    targetWorkerSizeId: 0
    
  }
}

output hostingPlanId string = hostingPlan.id
```

Template:

```
module AppService '../../Modules/Azure.App.Service.template.bicep'  = [for i in range(0, length(webAppSettings.webApps)): {
  name: webAppSettings.webApps[i].appServiceType == 'functionApp' ? toLower('fnc-${webAppSettings.webApps[i].name}-${resourceGroupNameSuffix}') : toLower('web-${webAppSettings.webApps[i].name}-${resourceGroupNameSuffix}')
  dependsOn: [
    AppServicePlan
  ]
  params: {
    hostingPlan: AppServicePlan.hostingPlan.id
    webAppSettings:webAppSettings
    vnetSubnetID:webAppSettings.webApps[i].appPurpose == 'backend' ? '${backendvnetSubnetID}' : '${frontendvnetSubnetID}'
    appServiceName:webAppSettings.webApps[i].appServiceType == 'functionApp' ? toLower('fnc-${webAppSettings.webApps[i].name}-${resourceGroupNameSuffix}') : toLower('web-${webAppSettings.webApps[i].name}-${resourceGroupNameSuffix}')
    appServiceType: webAppSettings.webApps[i].appServiceType
    LinuxFXVersion: webAppSettings.webApps[i].LinuxFX
  }
}]
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `hostingPlan.bicep` file, you can reference it from the `main.bicep` file like that:

```bicep
module hostingPlan 'hostingPlan.bicep' = {
  name: 'hostingPlan'
  params: {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can then access the outputs of the module:

```bicep
hostingPlan.outputs.hostingPlanId
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I worked out that i should be passing the output of the `appPlan` module as an array rather than a string. and then it worked.

Comment: Did that work for you ?